# how to access email inbox in php other than IMAP

Tags: php, imap

Is there any way to access emails from a server other than IMAP support in PHP ?

Regards,
Mithun

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with POP3 is stead of IMAP?
http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php